# How to shorten this symbolic expression?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

The symbolic expression below is the answer of some problem:

```
syms x y;
F = (6006059164170857*x^4)/36028797018963968 ...
    - (3741993627723215*x^3*y)/144115188075855872 ...
    - (3786059161694655*x^3)/576460752303423488 ...
    + (2057823154876729*x^2*y^2)/9007199254740992 ...
    + (7804706423002791*x^2*y)/36028797018963968 ...
    - (1579656551431947*x^2)/4503599627370496 ...
    - (5176864966130107*x*y^3)/576460752303423488 ...
    - (3350671128443929*x*y^2)/288230376151711744 ...
    - (2340405747630269*x*y)/72057594037927936 ...
    - (3122104315900301*x)/1152921504606846976 ...
    + (1757149312773205*y^4)/36028797018963968 ...
    - (5692299995057083*y^3)/576460752303423488 ...
    + (4054023049400589*y^2)/144115188075855872 ...
    - (434917661837037*y)/2251799813685248 ...
    - 2254148116991025/18014398509481984;
```

As you can see, it's too long to read, how could I shorten it to read easily?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%286006059164170857*x%5E4%29%2F36028797018963968+-+%283741993627723215*x%5E3*y%29%2F144115188075855872+-+%283786059161694655*x%5E3%29%2F576460752303423488+%2B+%282057823154876729*x%5E2*y%5E2%29%2F9007199254740992+%2B+%2878047064230) does a pretty good job on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) will do the numeric calculations as far as possible and returns the result with the precision defined by [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html).

See also [`latex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html) for *latex* representation of you symbolic expression,

```
digits(2) % Two digits precision
latex(vpa(F))

0.17\, x^4 - 0.026\, x^3\, y - \left(6.6\cdot 10^{-3}\right)\, x^3 + 0.23\, x^2\, y^2 + 0.22\, x^2\, y - 0.35\, x^2 - \left(9.0\cdot 10^{-3}\right)\, x\, y^3 - 0.012\, x\, y^2 - 0.032\, x\, y - \left(2.7\cdot 10^{-3}\right)\, x + 0.049\, y^4 - \left(9.9\cdot 10^{-3}\right)\, y^3 + 0.028\, y^2 - 0.19\, y - 0.13
```

and [`pretty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html) for nicer presentation in *command window*.

```
pretty(vpa(F))
                              3                                             3                                                    3 
        4          3     6.6 x          2  2         2           2   9.0 x y             2               2.7 x          4   9.9 y           2 
  0.17 x  - 0.026 x  y - ------ + 0.23 x  y  + 0.22 x  y - 0.35 x  - -------- - 0.012 x y  - 0.032 x y - ----- + 0.049 y  - ------ + 0.028 y  - 0.19 y - 0.13 
                             3                                            3                                 3                   3 
                           10                                           10                                10                  10
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have ended up with long integer like thin in the first place because you didn't create your symbolic equation in the best way. Compare the output of

```
sym(exp(pi))
```

to

```
exp(sym(pi))
```

Generally if you have any numeric constants in your symbolic equation that get transformed in complex ways (e.g., taking the exponential of them), you'll want to define them explicitly. If the constant is multiplied or added to a symbolic variable before being passed to the function then this may not be needed.

Additionally, you can use the [`simple`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simple.html) and [`simplify`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html) functions to try to nicer versions of expressions. In your case:

```
G = simple(F)
```

returns

```
(192193893253467424*x^4 - 29935949021785720*x^3*y ...
- 7572118323389310*x^3 + 263401363824221312*x^2*y^2 ...
+ 249750605536089312*x^2*y - 404392077166578432*x^2 ...
- 10353729932260214*x*y^3 - 13402684513775716*x*y^2 ...
- 37446491962084304*x*y - 3122104315900301*x ...
+ 56228778008742560*y^4 - 11384599990114166*y^3 ...
+ 32432184395204712*y^2 - 222677842860562944*y ...
- 144265479487425600)/1152921504606846976
```

which is slightly shorter (it may be a lot nice if you do what I suggest above). You can then go from there to @pm89's excellent suggestions if needed.